# Accessing loop variable inside of html.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

So I have a loop that goes through all of my articles and each article has a banner which contains a the name of a file (the png file). I ran into a problem when uploaded my files using heroku when i used this code:

```
<% @articles.visible.each do |article| %>
  <div class="article-card" style="background-image: url(/assets/blog_headers/<%=article.banner%>);">
```

more specifically with the url part I managed to get it working in another part of my application using this code:

```
url(<%= image_url('blog_headers/blog_header.png')%>)
```

I am now trying to implement the same logic here but I am having trouble accesing the article variable from the loop, this is what i currently have:

```
<div class="article-card" style="background-image:  url(<%= image_url('blog_headers/<%=article.banner%>')%>);">
```

Comment: you are using ruby inside ruby...use <%%> once...and dont use any nested ruby inside it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you are inside of an erb tag, (`<%= %>`) you are just plain ruby... you shouldn't use another, nested erb tag.

eg instead of:

```
<%= image_url('blog_headers/<%=article.banner%>')%>
```

Use:

```
<%= image_url("blog_headers/#{article.banner}")%>
```

Note that I've also changed the single quotes: `'` to double-quotes `"` so that the string is interpolated (and `#{}` gets evaluated as ruby)

Comment: Thank you!, I tried this before but was missing the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Inside **<%= image_url('blog_headers/<%=article.banner%>')%>** is all ruby. Do not use <% %> again. You can try this:

```
<%= image_url('blog_headers/'+article.banner+'\'')%>
```

or try this:

```
<div class="article-card" style='background-image:  url(<%= image_url("blog_headers/#{article.banner}")%>);'>
```

Just be careful about quotation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way you should apply on the views as below...

```
<div class="article-card">
 <%= image_tag("blog_headers/#{article.banner}")%>
</div>
```

If you don't have any text of message that should be appear on the image then you can use the above code to populates the images.

Otherwise set it to as a background image by assigning styles in the div tag.

Comment: Thank you! , this is also the right forgot to use double quotes!